Is it possible to come up with distinct strings with identical hashcodes algorithmically?
In Java we know some examples of strings which have identical hash codes despite being distinct strings, such as Ea and FB both having a hash code of 2236.
Is there a way, algorithmically, to come up with more examples of distinct strings sharing hash codes without using brute force testing of many strings, given we know the exact hashing algorithm used in each language?

Yes, but the solving algorithm is going to be different depending on the hashing algorithm. Are you looking for any specific one? I guess most generically, there are solvers like Z3.

I didn't have any in mind particularly, but I was curious as to the approach once given a hashing algorithm to come up with arbitrary collisions. I suppose if I were to try this myself it would be with Java's algorithm for strings

By "in each language" do you mean you want an algorithm that would work for every language? What if a language doesn't have a built-in concept of "hash code"? Or what if it uses a hash scheme that's specifically designed to resist this, e.g. with a random seed (as in Perl), or a deterministic but cryptographically secure hash like SHA-256?

I mean an approach for coming up with arbitrary examples of collisions giving a hashing algorithm. Doesn't even necessarily need to be for programming languages implementations but just in general

This is more a question for the maths stack exchange. There are some very interesting algorithms that use abstract properties of polynomials to attack cryptographic hashes and rule out vast numbers of possibilities to narrow the search range. LLL is probably the best known but other lattice reduction methods abound. You might find something suitable by asking people who fully understand those techniques.

No, there is no generic way to find collisions for different hash functions other than brute force. Each hash function must be analyzed on its own, and the techniques used to find collisions for one may be very different than the techniques used to find collisions for another. And this is assuming they are using non-cryptographic hash functions.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk There are algorithms that are smarter than pure brute force but they require fine tuning against the target hash function and quite a lot of computational power. The challenge here being to compute two strings with the same hash which is a lot easier than computing a pattern to match one specific hash value.

@MartinBrown: That's exactly what I wrote.


Is there a way, algorithmically, to come up with more examples of distinct strings sharing hash codes without using brute force testing of many strings, given we know the exact hashing algorithm used in each language?

Sometimes.  Let's take your Java example... "Ea and FB both having a hash code of 2236" and consider the hash function (here in C++, and only for ASCII strings):
int java_hash(const std::string& s) {
    int hash = 0;
    for (char c : s) (hash *= 31) += c;
    return hash;
}

We can see it starts by taking the value of the first character.  Then for two-character strings, it multiplies that by 31 and adds the next character.
Say we generalise and explain this: we have a two-character string KL (e.g. for "Ea", K == 'E' and L == 'a'); the hash value ends up being 31K + L.  Then to find a colliding key, we could try incrementing K to the next character value (e.g. 'F') which increases the hash output by 31, so to counter-balance we decrease L's character value by 31 (i.e. 'a'==ASCII 97 back to 'B'==66).
We can find yet another collision by incrementing to 'G' and decreasing to '#'.
Or, we could move in the other direction: if the new L value had been out of the valid value range for character types, we could instead decrement K and increase L by 31, still having a net-0 effect on the character value, but in this particular case "Ea" would need 'E' to become 'D', and 'a' to become 128, which may or may not be valid in your string type.
If we add more characters, we can observe something interesting - the overall hash value gets more complicated, but to create a collision we can still just screw with the last two characters in the same way, making sure their impact on the overall hash value is net-zero for our colliding keys.
With better and better hash functions, this kind of analysis becomes more and more difficult, and with uncompromised cryptographic strength functions it should be impractical even for an expert mathematician.  (That's why we see cryptocurrency mining having to use brute-force searches for "nonce" values in the key fields, seeking to create a desired overall hash value for the block.)
